# Cross-threading: Accessing a control from a different thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I think code talks clear

```
private void ucPerson_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    person = new Person();
    BackgroundWorker backgroundBinder = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundBinder.DoWork += BindComboBoxes;
    backgroundBinder.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void BindComboBoxes(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    cmbEducationLevel.DataSource = Program.eService.GetEducationLevels();
    cmbNationality.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cmbNationality.ValueMember = "NationalityID";
}
```

Error I get:

> **Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'cmbNationality' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.**

What need I do to make it possible for my `background-worker`'s thread to access the combobox?

Comment: You have to post-pone the assigning of the `DataSource` to after the worker finished running.

Comment: @UweKeim how can I find out when the worker has finished running? can you show me an example?

Comment: The `RunWorkerCompleted` is fired to your foreground thread. So doing the work in this handler, just as in the answer you accepted, is a good way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backgroundworker works in another thread : you are not allowed to call controls that belong to the calling thread in it.

As said Uwe Keim, you have to put everything that touches the controls in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event :

```
private void ucPerson_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    person = new Person();
    BackgroundWorker backgroundBinder = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundBinder.DoWork += GetData;
    backgroundBinder.RunWorkerCompleted += BindComboBoxes;
    backgroundBinder.RunWorkerAsync();
}

<<yourReturnType>> source;

private void GetData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    source = Program.eService.GetEducationLevels();
}

private void BindComboBoxes(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    cmbNationality.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cmbNationality.ValueMember = "NationalityID";
    cmbNationalty.DataSource = source;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome; I assume Program.eService.GetEducationLevels() takes a long time ;)

Comment: Yes actually we are taking this in mind that the user may be using a slow connection, and that's why we are using web services. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be the example of Laurent

Dirty way:

```
cmbEductionLevel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { mbEducationLevel.DataSource = Program.eService.GetEducationLevels(); });

cmbNationality.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { 
     cmbNationality.DisplayMember = "Name";
     cmbNationality.ValueMember = "NationalityID"; 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use Invoke and pass a delegate in order to update the control.

Comment: Invoking from a background thread, especially a background worker, seems like a bad design decision to me.